# WP 8.1 ToggleButton Change Icon when Checked / UnChecked

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, togglebutton

I have the following XAML code for **Windows Phone 8.1 (non SilverLight)**:

```
<Grid>
  <ToggleButton Name="TogBtn" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked">
    <SymbolIcon Symbol="play"></SymbolIcon>
  </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

The output of the above code is:

[image: toggle]

How can I change the icon to a `stop` icon when the toggle button is checked and then back to `play` icon when unchecked?

I thought this would be easy to find through Google, but apparently not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change your XAML to this:

```
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton x:Name="TogBtn" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Checked="ToggleButton_Checked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_Unchecked">
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Play"></SymbolIcon>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

And please add this to your .cs file:

```
private void ToggleButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TogBtn.Content = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Stop);
}

private void ToggleButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TogBtn.Content = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Play);
}
```

That should do the job!

Comment: How do I know whether I need the `x:` in front of the `Name` property or not? Is there a way, or is it a matter of experience?

Comment: I have never tried without the x:, because Visual Studio adds it automatically as I use the Properties-window to name items (which then creates the XAML).

Comment: Thanks! I prefer typing the XAML code in and thought there might be an easy way to know when to put the `x:` in.

Comment: It's actually a shortcut to the XAML namespace which then contains the Name property [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753327(v=vs.110).aspx)